# Get the top creators of goals

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building an Rails 5 app.
In this app I got two models, User and Goal.

A User can have many Goals.

I want to create a query to get the top five users that have created the most Goals.

This is the Goal scheme

```
create_table "goals", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "account_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "team_id"
    t.integer  "goal_id"
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.string   "gtype"
    t.datetime "starts_at"
    t.datetime "ends_at"
    t.string   "status",      default: "ontrack"
    t.string   "privacy"
    t.integer  "progress",    default: 0
    t.datetime "created_at",                      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                      null: false
    t.string   "ancestry"
    t.index ["account_id"], name: "index_goals_on_account_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["goal_id"], name: "index_goals_on_goal_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["team_id"], name: "index_goals_on_team_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_goals_on_user_id", using: :btree
  end
```

I tried this but then I only get the users not the ones with most goals.

```
Goal.distinct.order("user_id desc").limit(5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for you.

```
User.joins(:goals).select("users.*, count(goals.id) as goal_count").group("users.id").order("goal_count DESC").take(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Then the best way is to counter_cache the goles_count and order by it. Refer this http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column

The query will then be

```
User.order("users.goles_count DESC").limit(5)
```

Don't forget to index the goals_count column.
Other way out may be:

```
User
  .joins(:goals)
  .select("users.*, count(goals.id) as gcount")
  .group("users.id")
  .order("gcount DESC")
  .limit(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try rails scope method

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :top_user, -> (limit) { order("users.goles_count DESC").limit(limit) }
end
```

You can call this method in your controller

```
@top_user = User.top_user(5)
```